# Locust is not running

Tags: locust

**OS:** Windows 7 
**Locust version:** 0.11.0

I am exploring the locust tool to see if i can use this tool in my project.
I have created the below file to have hands-on but apparently script is not running.
I am not sure on the reason though.

Can someone help me please?

Locust.py:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet

def login(l):
    l.client.post("/login", {"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"})

def logout(l):
    l.client.post("/logout", {"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"})

def index(l):
    l.client.get("/")

def profile(l):
    l.client.get("/profile")

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    tasks = {index: 2, profile: 1}

def on_start(self):
    login(self)

def on_stop(self):
    logout(self)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

Output:

Tool kept running as below.

[image]

Comment: you have to go to `localhost:8089` to run it

Comment: looks like its running to me.  now visit the web ui and run your script

Comment: @DanielA.White am getting the below error while specifying host in command line. C DRive>locust -f http://IP ADDRESS:8089 Locustio.py
[2019-07-15 23:11:51,436] DESKTOP-ER32D9B/ERROR/locust.main: Could not find any locustfile! Ensure file ends in '.py' and see --help for available options. Note: .py file exists properly.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I am unable to access via web as well. Error This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Windows 10 and when I see the console in Chrome I see the below error. I think it is because of this that it is not working.
```Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.```

Answer (score 2):

With default arguments, you need to access the web monitor at `localhost:8089` in order to see the application.

If you want to run without the web frontend, you need to specify the arguments (clients, runtime, hatchrate, etc) in such a way to replicate what the webclient parameters are.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, by default the Web-host is listening on IPv6, so while accessing the site using http://0.0.0.0:8089 might yield *Error :This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.*

Run the locustby specifying the web-host as the argument. Then the web will be accessible.

```
locust --web-host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run locust in headless mode (without UI)  with below args to start the test automatically

```
locust -f locustio.py --headless -u 200 -r 10 --run-time 1h
```

`-u` specifies the number of Users to spawn.
`-r` specifies the spawn rate (number of users to start per second).
If you want to specify the run time for a test, you can do that with `--run-time` or `-t`

You can also run locust with head/UI.

```
locust -f locustio.py
```

Then go to **Locust’s web interface**

Once you’ve started Locust, you should open up a browser and point it to http://127.0.0.1:8089. Then you should be greeted with something like this:
[image]

Ref : https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html?#start-locust